# Syntax highlighting for JSX broken in VS Code for non-camelCase component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, jsx

Some recent update of VSCode has broken the syntax highlighting for any component props that are not written in camelCase.

How do I change the settings to "allow" and properly highlight?

.eslintrc.json

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "module": true,
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "object-curly-spacing": [1, "always"],
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "indent": ["error", 2],
    }
}
```

[image: Example of broken syntax highlighting for props in a React JSX component in VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was fixed in the latest release. Couldn't find anything about it in the release notes but the problem is gone for us now.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27